# Campo duración horas en Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, csv

Tengo un archivo .csv que incluye una columna duración con este formato `000:00:00` puede contener datos como estos `117:45:32` (Horas:Minutos:Segundos).

Al importar el csv a Access si indico que el tipo de dato de esta columna sea fecha/hora  todos los registros que sean superiores a 24 horas los inserta en una tabla aparte como datos erróneos.

Mi pregunta es.. ¿Cómo puedo tratar estos datos (Qué tipo de dato utilizar) para luego hacer consultas y por ejemplo sumar varios registros que cumplan una condición y sume correctamente las horas, minutos y segundos?

Comment: Yo creo que lo tienes que importar como texto (en lugar de fecha). Este link te puede dar ideas: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/664954-how-best-format-time-duration

Comment: Gracias, si lo importo como texto no me da problemas pero luego no puedo utilizar estos datos para sumar en una consulta por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso una idea que puede ayudar:

**A) Importar como Texto**

**B) Usar funciones que conviertan las duraciones a número y viceversa**

Entonces con estas funciones: sigues estos pasos:

1. Conviertes las duraciones a números
2. Realizas la suma o la resta entre números
3. Conviertes el resultado a duración nuevamente.

Te paso un link en donde hay dos funciones para hacer las conversiones. No las he probado. Las puedes probar o modificar según tu conveniencia.

Link: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/ms-access-sum-on-date-time-fields.3668627/

Código de las funciones:

```vb
Function LongToHHNNSS(Duration As Long) As String
    Dim lngHours As Long
    Dim lngMinutes As Long
    Dim lngSeconds As Long

    lngHours = Duration \ 3600
    lngMinutes = Duration Mod 3600
    lngMinutes = lngMinutes \ 60
    lngSeconds = Duration Mod 60

    LongToHHNNSS = lngHours & ":" & _
    Format(lngMinutes, "00") & ";" & _
    Format(lngSeconds, "00")

End Function

Function HHNNSSToLong(Duration As String) As Long
' Expects input to have two colons.
' Will return -1 if it doesn't.
    Dim varParts As Variant

    varParts = Split(Duration, ":")
    If UBound(varParts) = 2
        HHNNSSToLong = varParts(0) * 3600 +
        varParts(1) * 60 + varParts(2)
    Else
        HHNNSSToLong = -1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Gracias jpussacq por tu pronta respuesta, voy a probar esto.

Comment: Hola F. Funcionó la solución?

Comment: Hola jpussacq, al final era más sencillo que todo esto y he utilizado en las consultas las funciones de CInt(),  por ejemplo; CInt(Mid(columna,1,Len(columna)-6)).  Ya tengo el valor como entero. Gracias y Saludos.